# HTML hide and show - when does the code run?

Tags: html

In my page I have a  hidden `<div>`, such as the following:

```
<div id="myid"  style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
```

When the user clicks a button, I have a `javascript` code that calls `$('#myid').show("slow");`, thus displaying this `<div>`.

My question is when does the code inside the `<div>` gets called: when the page first loads or only when it's shown?

My concern is that inside this `<div>` I'd like to place a page counter (with an `<iframe>`), which should only be called when the `<div>` is shown. The alternative would be to put the code inside the `javascript`, but I'd rather keep it in the page.

Comment: When it's loaded. Since it exists in the DOM and not created by JavaScript it gets "read" by the browser when the parsing of the HTML file starts.

Comment: `display:none` doesn't mean it's not there, it just means it's not being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the div get called as you load the page.
So the counter will get called everytime the page is loaded even if the div stays hidden.
So you have to use javascript somehow like this:

```
<div id="myid"  style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>

<script>
function showCounter() {
    document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = '<script>counter-code</script>';
    document.getElementById("myid").show('slow');
}
</script>
```

and add the function showCounter to your button.

Answer (score 0):

It will be run when the page loads, `display:none` only affects visibility and has nothing to do with code operation layer (in fact, some browsers ignore CSS entirely and may show it anyway).

If you want a piece of code to only run when clicking a JavaScript button, you should attach that code to the Javascript function. Make an empty div on your page and then use the function to put code inside it:

```
<div id="jsDiv"></div>

<script>
function jsCode() {
    document.getElementById('jsDiv').innerHTML = 'Whatever you want';
}
</script>
```

Then attach the `jsCode()` function to your button, and the HTML will only be rendered when the function is called. If you're using server-side scripting (PHP, Rails etc.) or something more complex, look into [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) and [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) functions.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#myid').show("slow")
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this do? I'm not familiar with javascript, I'm just doing maintenance on this page.

Comment: he hasnt red your question xD
that just shows your div if the loading of the document finished.